# issue with for loop calculation using previous index

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data frame  that that looks similar to this:
df

```
   Year   GDP
   2010   6.100
   2011   7.572
   2012   8.560
```

I'm trying to calculate

```
`growth_percent = (current_GDP - previous_GDP)/(previous_GDP`)
```

and

```
growth_increase = current_GDP - past_GDP
```

I've been trying to use a for loop to solve this, but I am not sure how or if I am able to use a past index for the previous value in the situation.

Comment: Share your code...

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you shared your code but the below code should help you:

```
def main():
    GDP = [6.100,7.572,8.560]

    GROWTH_VEC = []
    for i in range(0,len(GDP) - 1):
        GROWTH_VEC.append( (GDP[i+1] -GDP[i])/GDP[i] ) 
    print(GROWTH_VEC)    



main()
```

**output**

```
[0.24131147540983613, 0.13048071843634448]
```

If your data is in a csv or text file you can read it in using `csv.reader` or read it into a `pandas` dataframe

Answer (score 0):

This would help:

```
x['GDP'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[1] / x[0])
```